# NoClassDefFoundError in OnCreate - happens only once in a while

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

For some strange reason, I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError when creating an instance of a class found in an Android library of my own (i.e. my own code, not a 3rd party library code).
This happens *rarely*, so it's not an issue of an invalid class path or what not.
And since it's my own class being instanciated, it's not an issue of a class that isn't defined in some Android versions.

Any thoughts on the matter?

Thanks

Comment: Happens to me aswell sometimes, also want to be enlighted!